# How to resolve 503 server problem when requesting from restcountries.com API?

Tags: api, server

https://restcountries.com/ Here I get 503 Server Problem. Does anyone know how I can solve it, it is my first time, that I get this Problem?

I would like to use this API for my Project.

Or Are there other REST APIs for County Information? Does anyone can help please? I am a beginner :)

MY CODE:

```
async function api(){
    const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all?fields=name,capital,region,languages,maps,population,flags';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    console.log(response);
}

api();
```

CONSOLE:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all?fields=name,capital,region,languages,maps,population,flags' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: Doesn't look like your issue is anything to do with CORS, inspecting the source for RestCountries shows that it allows requests from any origin (as you would expect any public API to do). Sometimes, this CORS error in the console can mask other issues with either your application or your network environment. Are you able to see the response contents in the network tab of your developer tools?